# How to rotate car marker image in Mapbox 3.6?

Tags: ios, swift, mapbox, cllocationcoordinate2d, mapbox-marker

I want to rotate marker image as per the route direction.I had implemented map using Map box SDK. Coordinates & directions are fetched through webservice.
I tried imageForMarker but it didnt work. Implemetation is as follow

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MGLMapView, imageFor annotation: MGLAnnotation) -> MGLAnnotationImage? {

    let img = imageRotatedByDegrees(oldImage: UIImage(named: "car")!, deg: CGFloat(self.bearing))

    return MGLAnnotationImage(image: img, reuseIdentifier: "car")
}
func imageRotatedByDegrees(oldImage: UIImage, deg degrees: CGFloat) -> UIImage
{
    let size = oldImage.size

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size)

    let bitmap: CGContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!
    //Move the origin to the middle of the image so we will rotate and scale around the center.
    bitmap.translateBy(x: size.width / 2, y: size.height / 2)
    //Rotate the image context
    bitmap.rotate(by: (degrees * CGFloat(Double.pi / 180)))
    //Now, draw the rotated/scaled image into the context
    bitmap.scaleBy(x: 1.0, y: -1.0)

    let origin = CGPoint(x: -size.width / 2, y: -size.width / 2)

    bitmap.draw(oldImage.cgImage!, in: CGRect(origin: origin, size: size))

    let newImage: UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()!
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    return newImage
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using a custom reuse identifier, like this:

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MGLMapView, imageFor annotation: MGLAnnotation) -> MGLAnnotationImage? {
    let annotation = annotation as! CustomMapAnnotation

    var annotationImage = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationImage(withIdentifier: annotation.id)

    if annotationImage == nil {
        var image = UIImage(named: "taxi")!

        if let heading = annotation.heading {
            image = image.imageRotatedByDegrees(degrees: heading)
        }
        image = image.withAlignmentRectInsets(UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: image.size.height/2, right: 0))

        annotationImage = MGLAnnotationImage(image: image, reuseIdentifier: annotation.id)
    }

    return annotationImage
}
```

Comment: If this annotation leaves the screen then comes back it's always going to be facing the same direction. If the value somehow gets updated, it won't be.  Which, for OP's case of tracking the current user's location, may not work.  Seems like a unique MGLAnnotationImage will need to be used each time, or at the very least break the possible headings down into intervals (say 30 or 15 degrees a pop), and have a single reuse identifier for each possible interval. The heading may not be exact, but close enough.  I'd go with 15 or 30 because that way you'll hit all four cardinal directions.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the proper way to do this is using an MGLSymbolStyleLayer with your annotation, instead of adding the annotation directly and using the mapview delegate method: https://www.mapbox.com/ios-sdk/api/3.6.2/Classes/MGLSymbolStyleLayer.html#/c:objc(cs)MGLSymbolStyleLayer(py)iconRotation

There is an iconRotation property you can use, which takes the degrees.

This is unfortunate as my use case has several of the same image but different headers, so I've got to add a layer for each one.