# Move MGLPointAnnotation on Mapbox Maps like uber

Tags: ios, swift, mapbox, mapbox-ios

I am integrating Mapbox iOS SDK into my app.
Right now I am stuck at a point where I want to achieve car tracking feature like Uber app.

I used to have that feature with Google Maps SDK but I cant make it work with Mapbox SDK.

I am adding `MGLPointAnnotation` object to add it on map and want to move it from point A to point B with animation.

I am doing it using

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: TimeInterval(duration), animations: {
    // Update annotation coordinate to be the destination coordinate
    point.coordinate = newCoordinate
}, completion: nil)
```

But for `MGLPointAnnotation` I can't change its image because when there's a turn I want to rotate the image(Annotation).

If I use `MGLAnnotationView` object I can change the image but I cant change its coordinate because its readonly.

What should I do here to achieve that functionality?

Comment: As I know point changes its position animated by default, you need to rotate image of your marker

Comment: Changing the position is not a problem. I want to rotate marker's image after its added on map view, which I can't do it when I am using MGLPointAnnotation object.

Comment: I think you need marker.rotation property

Comment: The annotation might not be a UIView object but a layer instead. Try CATransition begin and commit instead.

Comment: @AlexandrKolesnik Can you elaborate?

Comment: @Robin Are you trying to say I should use CATransition to change marker's position?

Answer (score 0):

Several years ago I wrote smth similar, I used GoggleMaps, look through the code, maybe it will be helpful, I really don't remember what are all that numbers in angle counting

```
    extension Double {

    var degrees: Double {
        return self * 180.0 / Double.pi
    }

}


extension CLLocationCoordinate2D {

    func angleToPosition(position : CLLocationCoordinate2D) -> CLLocationDegrees {
        let bearingRadians = atan2(Double(position.latitude - latitude), Double(position.longitude - longitude))
        var bearingDegrees = bearingRadians.degrees
        //        print("\(bearingDegrees)")
        var roundDegrees = 360.0
        if bearingDegrees < 0 {
            if bearingDegrees > -90 {
                roundDegrees = 350
            }
            if bearingDegrees < -90 && bearingDegrees > -180 {
                roundDegrees = 370
            }
            bearingDegrees += roundDegrees
            return 360 - bearingDegrees
        }
        roundDegrees = bearingDegrees < 90 ? 350 : 360
        if bearingDegrees > 90 && bearingDegrees < 180 {
            roundDegrees = 370
        }
        UserDefaults.standard.set(bearingDegrees, forKey: "bearingDegrees")
        return roundDegrees - bearingDegrees
    }

    func duration(toDestination destination: CLLocationCoordinate2D, withSpeed speed : Double) -> Double {
        let distance = GMSGeometryDistance(self, destination)
        return distance / (speed * (1000 / 3600))
    }

}
```

And this is the func which do the rotation, you can use it as soon as you receive new coordinates, or call it in for loop if you have certain polyline

```
func animateCarDrive(info: [String: Any]) {
    let speed = info["speed"] as? Double ?? 40 // if your car's speed is changeable
    let position = info["position"] as? CLLocationCoordinate2D // new point position
    let duration = marker.position.duration(toDestination: position, withSpeed: speed)
    marker.rotation = marker.position.angleToPosition(position: position)
    CATransaction.begin()
    CATransaction.setAnimationDuration(duration)
    marker.position = position
    CATransaction.commit()
}
```

Comment: I am not sure whether you understood my question or not. I am not looking for a solution for Google Maps SDK, I am looking for Mapbox SDK. I already have working code for Google Maps SDK but its not the same for Mapbox SDK.

Comment: You are right, try this solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45907301/how-to-rotate-car-marker-image-in-mapbox-3-6

Comment: I think you still dont understand my question. May I Suggest to read full question. I can rotate the image for a marker and add it onto map but the main issue is MGLPointAnnotation doesn't allow to rotate a marker's image after its added on mapview.

Comment: I want to avoid adding it again.

Comment: There seem to be no solution in that link for that issue.